# Share data between app users without login

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I am quite new to app development and have started doing Android Apps in Java.
For my second app, I need some basic guidance, I could not find it on the internet so far.

I want to have an App (without a backend/web application) where two or more users can work together on some data. Let's take the example of a shopping cart. One person can add items to the cart, and the other can tick them during shopping.

Now on my first look, I have chosen the Firestore database since the free tier is sufficient for me and it is well integrated into Android Studio. But after going deeper it sounds quite wrong from a security perspective since I do not want that my users need to have an account to log in.

So - what is the way to solve such things? I do not need code examples, that I will find out. But I need some guidance on how things like that are usually done.

Comment: You could, of course, embed the credentials (username, password, etc) in your application, or work out some web service or something to retrieve them. But you must provide security for your app and its servers, or you **will be pwned** by cybercriminals and probably within hours of going live. You don't even want to think about the content they could put on your service. What kind of security will you offer? Please [edit] your question.

Comment: I am aware, that i must take care about security - that is why I am asking. I am not sure what you mean with "what kind of security" - I did not really start working on the app yet.

Comment: Your requirement of "without login" is working entirely against you.  You should require a login using Firebase Auth, and use security rules to determine who can read and write which data in Firestore.  There is really no other secure way to do this.  Without requiring a login or a backend, your only alternative is to allow everyone full access to everything.

Comment: Have a look at Firebase Authentication's anonymous sign-in. This allows you to sign in the users without requiring them to enter any credentials: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/anonymous-auth. Once the user is signed in, they have a unique user ID (UID) that you can use to coordinate sharing of data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to implement a traditional authentication mechanism, that allows you to write security rules, then as @FrankvanPuffelen mentioned in his comment, your option would be to [authenticate your users in Firebase anonymously](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/anonymous-auth). What are the benefits?

- You can create a sharing feature in your app based on the user ID.
- You can secure your data using [security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started).
- You can create an account without the need to ask the user for any information.
- It's very easy to implement. If you understand Kotlin, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-handle-firebase-authentication-in-clean-architecture-using-jetpack-compose-e9929c0e31f8) will help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirebaseAnonymousAuthentication).

Comment: Hey Zudy. Did my answer help? Can I help you with other information?

Comment: Hey, I did not have time for that project in a while. At my first sights and test codes, this looks like what I was looking for. Thanks mate!